# Cannot use use ref or out parameter for anonymous methods

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
    static BackgroundWorker worker; 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
      worker = new BackgroundWorker();
      worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork; 
      worker.RunWorkerAsync();
      Console.ReadLine(); 
    } 
    static void worker_DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e) 
    { 
      string strClientId = "2211"; Authenticate(ref strClientId); 
    }
    static void Authenticate(ref string strClientId) 
    {
       Timer timer = new Timer(500); 
       //Error in this line 
       //Cannot use ref or out parameter 'strClientId' inside an anonymous method,lambda expression or query expression
       timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Authenticates_Timer(sender, e,ref strClientId); 
       //timer.Elapsed += Authenticates_Timer();
       timer.Start(); 
    } 
    static void Authenticates_Timer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, ref string strClientId)
    { 
      //want to use variable here 
      strClientId = "";
    }
```

if there is a way i can use ref variable while passing
parameter to event Cannot use ref or out parameter 'strClientId'
inside an anonymous method,lambda expression or query
expression.I know this is repeated question but i am unable to
figure out how to solve this have refered different posts and
posted question in codeproject too but no one is responding any
help is appreciated

Comment: You could always create a class which has a field to hold the client id. Then pass an instance of the class around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend sharing `strClientId` as static variable:

```
static BackgroundWorker worker; 
static string strClientId;
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
  worker = new BackgroundWorker();
  worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork; 
  worker.RunWorkerAsync();
  Console.ReadLine(); 
} 
static void worker_DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{ 
  strClientId = "2211";
  Authenticate(); 
}
static void Authenticate() 
{
   Timer timer = new Timer(500); 
   timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Authenticates_Timer(sender, e); 
   timer.Start(); 
} 
static void Authenticates_Timer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{ 
  strClientId = "";
}
```

Will it work for you?

Update: Ok, let's try this one:

```
static void worker_DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{ 
  string strClientId = "";
  var setClientId = new Action<string>(v => { strClientId = v; });
  setClientId("2211");
  Authenticate(setClientId); 
}

static void Authenticate(Action<string> setClientId) 
{
  Timer timer = new Timer(500); 
  timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Authenticates_Timer(sender, e, setClientId); 
  timer.Start();    
}

static void Authenticates_Timer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, Action<string> setClientId)
{ 
  setClientId("");
}
```

Comment: I know i can use static but my team lead said not to use static.

Comment: can the changed value also be reflected in dowork event

Comment: I think so. The action is actually a closure so you can pass reference to it almost anywhere in the current AppDomain and it should work.

Comment: can you elaborate on how i can use action<string> setClientId in dowork that would really help boss

Comment: I've added the example into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that:

```
static void Authenticate(ref string strClientId) 
{
       Timer timer = new Timer(500); 
       var strClientIdVar = strClientId;
       timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Authenticates_Timer(sender, e,ref strClientIdVar);
       timer.Start(); 
}
```